# google script How to compare cells in two columns and set value to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have unique ID ('ID1') in column A in sheet1 and I need to compare it with column B in sheet2 where are ID ('ID2') to.

So I need to compare those of ID and check if some of them match, if they are I want to change value of cell in the same row as 'ID1' in sheet1 but in another column, let say C.

```
function IDValidation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var Sheet1range = sheet1.getRange(2,1,sheet1.getLastRow()); //header is row 1
  var Sheet2range = sheet2.getRange(2, 2);    //header is row 1
  var Sheet1cellValue = Sheet1range.getValues();
  var Sheet2cellValue = Sheet2range.getValues();//Look here

  for(i = 0; i<Sheet1cellValue .length-1; i++){
     if(Sheet1cellValue [i][0] == Sheet2cellValue)
     {
       ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(i+2,3).setValue("Close");

}
}
}
```

Comment: Sheet2cellValue is an array.  Have you tried comparing to Sheet2cellValue[0][0]?

Comment: It didn't work, even if I expanded Sheet2range by var Sheet2range = sheet2.getRange(2, 2,sheet2.getLastRow(). It shows only the first match, not all

Comment: `var Sheet2range = sheet2.getRange(2, 2);` is only getting one cell.  Changing it to `var Sheet2range = sheet1.getRange(2,2,sheet2.getLastRow());` will get all the rows starting at 2,2 as an array so you would have to search i the array.  The simple method would be a second for loop inside the first, looping on each item in Sheet2cellValue and comparing it to Sheet1cellValue[i][0].  NOTE that using .getLastRow() will get all the empty rows as well, so any blank rows will match.

Comment: I know my script get's only cell. I've tried your way but it didn't work to. I think it's because sheet1 don't have range from sheet2 like you wrote. I've try also var Sheet2range = sheet2.getRange(2, 2,sheet2.getLastRow() but it get only first match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options.

Try this:

```
function IDValidation() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh1rg=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow()); //header is row 1
  var sh2rg=sh2.getRange(2,2);//header is row 1
  var sh1cvA=sh1rg.getValues();
  var sh2cV=sh2rg.getValue();//look here
  for(var i=0;i<sh1cvA.length-1; i++){
    if(sh1cvA[i][0]==sh2cV){
      sh1.getRange(i+2,3).setValue("Close");
    }
  }
}
```

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

That seems to work.

---

I don't know, perhaps you're looking for all matches between Sheet1 Column1 and Sheet2 Column2.  That's what this function does.  I'm using random numbers between 0 and 50 and not unique Ids so there are many matches.  I stopped putting `close` in column3 and started describing where the matches are.

Here's the code:

```
function IDValidation1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh1rg=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1); //header is row 1
  var sh2rg=sh2.getRange(2,2,sh2.getLastRow(),1);//header is row 1
  var sh1cvA=sh1rg.getValues();
  var sh2cvA=sh2rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sh1cvA.length-1; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<sh2cvA.length;j++) {
      if(sh1cvA[i][0]==sh2cvA[j][0]){
        sh1.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(Utilities.formatString('Sheet2 Row:%s == Sheet1 Row:%s = %s',j+2,i+2,sh1cvA[i][0]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's Sheet1 after running:

[image]

And this is Sheet2: (I picked too many rows and couldn't fit them all on my screen)

[image]

Comment: You've change only name of var. It's not change anything in script

Comment: Look at line 8 in both your version and mine.

Comment: You could also change this `if(Sheet1cellValue [i][0] == Sheet2cellValue)` to this `if(Sheet1cellValue [i][0] == Sheet2cellValue{0][0])`

Comment: It didn't work either. If in line 8 is Value + Sheet2cellValue[0][0] I get the message: "0" property can not be read. If it is Values + Sheet2cellValue[0][0] it get only match from sheet2 B2 not the whole column. If I get Values + Sheet2cellValue[0][0] + line 6 --> var Sheet2range = sheet2.getRange(2, 2, sheet2.getLastRow());it get only first match not all.

Comment: I don't understand this line `I have unique ID ('ID1') in column A in sheet1 and I need to compare it with column B in sheet2 where are ID ('ID2') to`.  Can you explain it better.

Comment: In fact your entire explanation is very difficult to understand which is probably why no one else has tried to answer the question.  I was simply trying to correct some inconsistencies in your code in the hopes that it would help.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your spreadsheet and show an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're understood everything very well because your code is the answer to my problem :) I added only in row '10' -1 with length to not count the last row in sheet2 which is empty. And I will change setValue of course. Thanks fo all.

```
function IDValidation1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sh1rg=sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1); //header is row 1
  var sh2rg=sh2.getRange(2,2,sh2.getLastRow(),1);//header is row 1
  var sh1cvA=sh1rg.getValues();
  var sh2cvA=sh2rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<sh1cvA.length-1; i++){
    for(var j=0;j<sh2cvA.length-1;j++) {
      if(sh1cvA[i][0]==sh2cvA[j][0]){
        sh1.getRange(i+2,3).setValue(Utilities.formatString('Sheet2 Row:%s == Sheet1 Row:%s = %s',j+2,i+2,sh1cvA[i][0]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```